# Textfield Tags and Tableviews

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a custom tableview cell set up for the "edit profile" viewcontroller on the current app Im developing. The custom cell has a label (for the category) and a textfield for the inputs. For example:
"Name(label)   John Doe(Input)"
Im using an array for the label titles an another for the placeholders within the textfields. What I want to do is access each individual textfield so that I can set the initial text (information the user has stored to the server). How can I go about accessing a specific textfield? My guest is that I have to base it off of the specific indexPath, but Im not too sure. Is there a way i can set each textfields tag programmatically so that I can easily access them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try this:

At first create a subclass for that particular cell.

put a textfield and add delegate

in numberofrows func:

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return 4//return whatever you want
    }
```

in cellForRowAtIndexPath func:

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


                 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! customCell
                cell.textfld.tag = indexPath.row//this is the textfield in cell
cell.textfld.delegate = self
                cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.Gray
                return cell
        }
```

textFieldDidBeginEditing func:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) { 
   //delegate method

        print(textField.tag)//here you will get particular textfield tag.
    }
```

Hope it will work for you......

Answer (score 0):

You do not access each text field. Cell's are to be reused which means the labels and text fields will be reused. All of the data belongs in your data model. Then in your `cellForRowAt` method you go to your data model and get that cell's data and populate the cell.

Your view controller should also be the delegate for each cell's text field. Whenever a text field is updated, you update your data model with the new text.

Doing this ensures your data model is always the most up-to-date and always contains all data for all rows. Do not use your cells to hold data. Only use them to show data.

Using tags on each text field to correspond to its current row can work but only if the table rows can't be altered (reordered, deleted, and only added to at the end of the current rows).

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are not reusing cells (which you shouldn't in this case), you could easily create a global reference (inside your view controller) to these text fields inside `cellForRow:atIndexPath`. That way you'll always have access to your text fields, without having to deal with cells.

Comment: So should I create multiple cells with different identifiers?

Comment: Stating that cells shouldn't be reused in this case is bad advice.